# Bind to RibbonGalleryCategory value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ribbon combo with two values - how could I bind my textbox to one of this values? So if combo is OFF - textbox is disabled?
my combo

```
 <RibbonComboBox x:Name="combo1" IsEditable="True">
    <RibbonGallery x:Name="content1" SelectedValue="OFF"
                                       SelectedValuePath="Content"
                                       MaxColumnCount="1">
                                        <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                                            <RibbonGalleryItem Content="ON" />
                                            <RibbonGalleryItem Content="OFF" />
                                        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                                    </RibbonGallery>
                                </RibbonComboBox>
```

And there is my style for textbox:

```
 <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=???no combo1 nor content1
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
```

the problem is that there is no combo1 or content1 names in drop-down list of suggested names - so I think this elements is out of view?

I could see StackPanel (that keeps combo1 control), but how could I access this combo1 or content 1 in XAML?

Sorry for the question - all problems with visibility were solved with rebuild...

Comment: Which statck panel are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I have solved this issue

Comment: where is you TextBox located relative to your combobox ?